# Best practice when using same query repeatedly

Tags: sql, oracle

what is the alternative for using same query repeatedly many times. I want to store the query in some place and call it  whenever I need it.
I'm computing 4 formulas: MTD sales, MTD previous year sales, MAT sales, MAT previus year sales as separate columns for 5 different products: A,B,C,D,E. along with some static conditions like account details should be provided and direct sales

I'm querying Case statements 4 (for formulas)* 5 (for products) times to define formula with static conditions for all 5 products. i.e. almost 80% of my query is repeated for 4*5 =20 times. Instead of repeating 80% of the query for all 20 times, is there any better way to do it. Kindly note, I don't have to store value of the query as function, instead can I store the repeated portion of the query and call it where ever I need?

Code:

```sql
SELECT A1.*,

-- MTD FOR PRODUCTS A,B,C,D

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='A'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A)))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PRODUCT_A,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='B'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A)))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PRODUCT_B,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='C'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A)))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PRODUCT_C,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='D'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A)))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PRODUCT_D,

---MTD LAST YEAR FOR PRODUCTS A,B,C,D

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='A'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(SHOWN_DATE))-1 FROM TABLE_A))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_A,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='B'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(SHOWN_DATE))-1 FROM TABLE_A))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_B,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='C'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(SHOWN_DATE))-1 FROM TABLE_A))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_C,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='D'
AND
(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE_MONTH)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT MAX(SHOWN_DATE) FROM TABLE_A))
AND 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_MONTH)=(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(SHOWN_DATE))-1 FROM TABLE_A))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_D,


----MAT SALES FOR PRODUCT A,B,C,D

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='A'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-11)
and
trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='B'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-11)
and
trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_B,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='C'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-11)
and
trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_C,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='D'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-11)
and
trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_D,


---MAT LAST YEAR SALES FOR PRODUCTS A,B,C,D

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='A'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-23)
and
add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-12))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='B'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-23)
and
add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-12))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_B,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='C'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-23)
and
add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-12))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_C,

CASE WHEN
ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided' AND TYPE<> 'DIRECT' and PRODUCT='D'
AND
(Date_Month between add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-23)
and
add_months(trunc((SELECT MAX(Date_Month) AS MAX_DATE_DIST FROM TABLE_A),'month'),-12))
THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS MAT_PRODUCT_D

FROM TABLE_A A1
```

Comment: can you post your query?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the SQL statement(s) you are using.

Comment: *" can I store the repeated portion of the query and call it where ever I need"*. Yes. It's called the WITH clause and it's been part of the SELECT statement since Oracle 9i. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)

Comment: Hi MTO / Kiran gadhe, edited the post and added the complete query with arbitrary column and object name.

Comment: If you want to attract somebody's attention you need to prefix their handle with `@` (one per comment). Also you should use the formatting markup when posting code, especially when it's such a large chunk of code. People are less likely to bother with questions which are hard to read.

Comment: @kirangadhe, I have updated the post with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an analytical function to find the maximum date value:

```sql
SELECT A1.*,
       CASE
         WHEN ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided'
         AND  TYPE<> 'DIRECT'
         AND  PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month_trunc = max_date_month
         THEN SALES
         ELSE 0
       END AS MTD_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN ACCOUNT <> 'Not Provided'
         AND  TYPE<> 'DIRECT'
         AND  PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month_trunc = max_date_month - INTERVAL '1' YEAR
         THEN SALES
         ELSE 0
       END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided'
         AND  TYPE<> 'DIRECT'
         AND  PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month - 11 ) AND max_date_month
         THEN SALES
         ELSE 0
       END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided'
         AND  TYPE<> 'DIRECT'
         AND  PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month, -23 ) AND ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month, -12 )
         THEN SALES
         ELSE 0
       END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A
       /* B, C, D */
FROM (
  SELECT a.*,
         TRUNC( date_month, 'MM' ) AS date_month_trunc,
         MAX( TRUNC( date_month, 'MM' ) ) OVER () AS max_date_month
  FROM   TABLE_A a
) A1
```

You could make it even shorter by moving common elements of the `CASE` to the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT A1.*,
       CASE
         WHEN PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month_trunc = max_date_month
         THEN not_provided_direct_sales
         ELSE 0
       END AS MTD_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month_trunc = max_date_month - INTERVAL '1' YEAR
         THEN not_provided_direct_sales
         ELSE 0
       END AS MTD_PY_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month - 11 ) AND max_date_month
         THEN not_provided_direct_sales
         ELSE 0
       END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A,
       /* B, C, D */
       CASE
         WHEN PRODUCT='A'
         AND  date_month BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month, -23 ) AND ADD_MONTHS( max_date_month, -12 )
         THEN not_provided_direct_sales
         ELSE 0
       END AS MAT_PRODUCT_A
       /* B, C, D */
FROM (
  SELECT a.*,
         CASE
           WHEN ACCOUNT<> 'Not Provided'
           AND  TYPE<> 'DIRECT'
           THEN SALES
           ELSE 0
         END AS not_provided_direct_sales,
         TRUNC( date_month, 'MM' ) AS date_month_trunc,
         MAX( TRUNC( date_month, 'MM' ) ) OVER () AS max_date_month
  FROM   TABLE_A a
) A1
```

Comment: @MTO even in this case I have to repeat the same query for B,C,D right? (in your commented piece of the query)? Is there any way to store this each step of case when in a string variable and call the variable where ever required? My intention is to avoid repeated querying for B,C,D

Comment: @Durgaprasad You could use a `PIVOT` to do that. However it is just a simple copy/paste/replace to write out all the different cases and it will probably be a much more efficient query that trying to do it generically and then pivot to have all the data in separate columns.

Comment: @Durgaprasad This is probably just a matter of terminology but you do not need to repeat the "query" for B, C and D. You do need to repeat the "case statements" and although it will make for a long query it will not be inefficient.

Comment: @MTO got it, instead of copy paste, is there any possibility to store it in a string variable and call it? So that query is not looking humongous?

Comment: @MTO, your revised query suggestion helps, another clarification: Is it optimal to do it as direct sub query or is there any way to do it using With clause?

Comment: A `WITH` clause is properly named a "sub-query factoring clause" and is just another way of presenting a sub-query (and naming the sub-query so that it can be reused in multiple places). In the context here, you are referencing the sub-query (or the `WITH` clause) only once so there should be no difference in performance. As ever though, with matters of performance, if you are worried about it you should test both methods and use the one that is "best" (where "best" can be measured in terms of performance, readability, maintainability or any other number of metrics).

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

If the underlying data only needs to be created periodically -- say, once per day or once per week, then you can schedule a job and create a table.  This is probably the most common solution across different databases for complicated queries.

If the query itself is not particularly complicated or if you need up-to-date data every time, then use a (regular) view.  This is the built-in functionality for encapsulating queries.

Another alternative is a materialized view.  These are like tables, in that the data does not need to be (explicitly) recalculated.  These are like views, in that the data is kept up-to-date.  You can learn more about them in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm#BABCCHDA).